# Difference between DataMember and JsonProperty in webapi2

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

What is the difference between DataMember and JsonProperty when using it in webapi2? Any performance differences? What is preferred to use?

Thanks!
Andreas

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In WebAPI, the default JSON formatter is [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json).

Json.NET is the one who reads the DataMember and JsonProperty attributes. JsonProperty is from Json.NET and its purpose is to control how the field or property is serialized. While DataMember, which is from Microsoft, is read by Json.NET for convenience.

[JsonProperty](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/AllMembers_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) provides more configuration options than DataMember.

Comment: I question if *DataMember* is actually read by Json.NET because I just had the issue where I dutyfully attributed all my variables with the former but the code didn't start working until I changed it to the latter. Is that perhaps due to a change between version of Json.NET?

Comment: Add DataContractAttribute to your class.