# How should one interpret this JSON structure?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, parsing, json.net

I've just started to work with JSON and after having read a few articles, I'm still unclear if I'm looking at an array, list or just an object. It looks like this.

```
{
  "list": [{
    "fields": {
      "id": "9222115557374550596",
      ...
    },
  },
  {
    "fields": {
      "id": "9222115557374550597",
      ...
    },
  }],
  "paging": {
    "pageCurrent": 0,
    "itemMin": 0,
    "itemMax": 2,
    "maxNextPages": 0,
    "pageSize": 100
  }
}
```

I'd like to deserialize it to be a list (or *IEnumerable*) of objects typed so that there's an *Id* property (perhaps not **all** fields have to be parsed in to the object).

When I try to do that using the following code:

```
List<Some> somes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Some>>(dataAbove);

class Some { public String Id { get; set; } }
```

I get a long error message about me not being using the correct type and array and a bunch of other stuff that makes me confused. Am I on the right track or did I totally went off and got lost?!

I understand it's something with the *list* at the root. But what?! Or at least - what should I google for?!

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ScriveProxy.Template]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\u000d\u000aTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\u000d\u000aPath 'list', line 1, position 8."

It can't be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557559/cannot-deserialize-the-json-array-e-g-1-2-3-into-type-because-type-requ) because the outer brackets are curly not squary...

In [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358493/cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-object-e-g-namevalue-into-type-sy), we end up with a single object, not an array, so it's not what I'm aiming for neither.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, `"list"` is an array of `"fields"` objects.

`"paging"` is an object.

Both `` "list"` and `` "paging"` are in an un-named root object.

#### Working dotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4qLTvq

See the output in the console pane of the fiddle above.

Here's How you should declare your Classes for Deserializing this particular JSON into C# Classes.

```
public class Fields
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class TheFields
{
    public Fields fields { get; set; }
}

public class Paging
{
    public int pageCurrent { get; set; }
    public int itemMin { get; set; }
    public int itemMax { get; set; }
    public int maxNextPages { get; set; }
    public int pageSize { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute("list")] 
    public List<TheFields> FieldsList { get; set; }
    public Paging paging { get; set; }
}
```

And here's how you would deserialize the whole thing.

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

Since `List` is a keyword, and to avoid confusion and collision, I changed it's Name to `FieldsList` and also renamed the `List` class to `TheFields` class. You may choose any other name(s) that you feel is appropriate.

#### Explanation on `Object` vs `Array`

An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace). Each name is followed by : (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by , (comma).

[image: object]

An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with [ (left bracket) and ends with ] (right bracket). Values are separated by , (comma).

[image: array]

Source: http://www.json.org/

Comment: Do I control how the data string is fetched and formatted at the call time? Or is it so that if the server gives me outer curleys I can't get them as squareys, period? +1 for pedagogical approach and images!

Comment: Usually the caller (your code) does not have control over the sender (the server  / code sending the JSON). I use this site => http://json2csharp.com/ to generate the correct C# classes with nesting from a given JSON (should be valid) string.

Comment: I added a working dotNetFiddle to my answer. Check it out. Everything works nicely! https://dotnetfiddle.net/4qLTvq

Comment: Oh, after watching like a moron for an hours I realize the problem - my *DataMember* isn't working... You mean that I have to use *JsonPropertyAttribute* and not *DataMember* to map *list* to *Donkey*?! Such an information should be presented somewhere... Like a documentation or something...   :)   However, I went *[JsonProperty("list")]* instead. Is that the same or will it come back and bite me too?

Comment: Read this - "JsonProperty Vs DataMember". http://stackoverflow.com/a/20579372/325521 . Short answer, for serializing and deserializing JSON and naming the Properties, use `JsonProperty`. Also, don't beat yourself up and be so hard on yourself. The key thing is that you figured it out yourself, so you will never forget this ever again :)

Comment: Great answer. If I wouldn't be so stingy with my rep, I'd bounty you, for sure, hahaha. One thing in the images, though, that seems to differ from what I expected - it says that the combo is *string:value* but all the JSON structures I've seen are *string:string*... Technically, the other string is a value but I've only seen string typed values ("1", not 1). Is my reference horizon too narrow?

Answer (score 1):

If it starts with { it's an object.
If it starts with [ it's an array.